# Why weren't ICO's possible before cryptocurrencies?

Tags: ico

ICO’s are used today to distribute and fund decentralized products. I’m curious why companies, before Bitcoin, could not have launched the sale of their own centralized currencies or reward points of some sort. If it were technically feasible before in a centralized form, why did we never see such a thing?